# Here's a bit of javascript used to shuffle, or randomize, an array. Can someone explain it piece by piece how it works?

Tags: javascript, random

```
for(var j, x, i = answerArr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = answerArr[--i], answerArr[i] = answerArr[j], answerArr[j] = x);
        for(var t = 0; t < answerArr.length; t++)
        {
            $("#kc_answers").append('<li><span class="kc_answer_span">' + $(answerArr[t]).find('aText').text() + '</span></li>');
        }
```

***Can someone explain step by step what different parts of the code are doing?***

It seems to be a pretty common code, altered somewhat to append parts of the array to a div in a random order. I understand a good ammount of javascript and jquery, but I don't quite have my head wrapped around this.

I think it would be useful to others as well, since this code is shuffling an array and spitting out the peices into html. Seems like that could be a common need.

Comment: The use of `parseInt()` to truncate a float indicates that this code was probably written by an inexperienced JavaScript coder.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't write this, but I am an inexperienced JavaScript coder. What's incorrect about the use of parseInt()? According to its description on w3schools, it seems like it should work for this purpose. Is there a more correct solution?

Comment: Well it's kind-of the hard way to do things; the function coerces the argument to a string and then parses it again. The `Math.floor()` function is more straightforward. My point wasn't to critique the code, however; I simply meant that if you're using this as an example, it's not "industrial strength" (though it's so simple it probably makes no difference here).

Comment: I agree with using `Math.floor()`. It says exactly what's going on. When using `parseInt` you have to remember how it handles floats. That's not code clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be rewritten as:

```
    // loop from arrayArr.length - 1 to 0
    for (var randomIndex, temp, i = answerArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // get a random index in the array.
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        // put the current index in a temporary variable
        temp = answerArray[i];
        // assign the random index to the current index
        answerArr[i] = answerArr[randomIndex];
        // assign the temporary variable to the random index
        answerArr[randomIndex] = temp;
    }
    // now output the new shuffled array
    for(var t = 0; t < answerArr.length; t++)
    {
        $("#kc_answers").append('<li><span class="kc_answer_span">' + $(answerArr[t]).find('aText').text() + '</span></li>');
    }
```

**Update**

Regarding the `for loop` having no body, basically this is how a `for loop` works:

```
for (run what is in here once;
     evaluate this each time after the next statement and the body... if it evalutes to false then exit;
     run what is here each time after the body)
{
    // run this until the second statement is false
}
```

So the author of the original code is doing is this:

```
for (run this once;
     evaluate this expression each time;
     forget having a body, just put everything in here!!);
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why my code doesn't use any curly braces, or why it's possible too? I can't seem to find much information on for loops without curly braces. Is this bad syntax?

Comment: I updated the answer to respond to your question. Yeah, it's possible to put everything in the third statement and not have a body, but in my opinion it makes the code harder to understand so it should be avoided--especially if you're working with other programmers.

Comment: This helps a lot. So just to be clear, since `i` is simply the legnth of the array, and there's no expression such as `i = answerArr.length - 1` in your version, does this mean it's evaluating to false when `i` decrements down to 0 in the example I provided?

Comment: `i` specifies an index in the array from `answerArr.length - 1` to `0`. Say `answerArr.length` is `5`. So it swaps index `4` with a different random index, then index `3` with a different random index, and it goes all the way down to index `0`. Once i is decremented to `-1`, then `i` is NOT `>= 0` so it exists the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle). Pretty common indeed.